# htmx: Update parent-Fragment if child-form is valid

Tags: htmx

I am learning the "html fragments over the wire" approach of [htmx](//htmx.org).

I have a "parent" tag in my HTML page which contains a child which is a form.

Case1: If the child form gets submitted and is not valid, then I want to re-display the child form (`hx-swap="outerHTML"`). This works fine.

Case2: if the child form gets submitted and is valid, then I want to re-fresh the parent.

I had a look at [hx-swap-oob](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-swap-oob/), but this needs to be an attribute of the HTML send from the serve to the client.

This is possible, but it is a bit dirty to get the attribute into the parent tag.

Is there a way to trigger something like oob, but why http-header?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the rest of your website, I'd suggest using the [hx-trigger response header](https://htmx.org/headers/hx-trigger/) to trigger a new event on your website when your form is posted successfully.  You can use htmx, [hyperscript](https://hyperscript.org), javascript, or anything else listen for this event and take the necessary action.